# Add errors from Gulp Typescript task to WebStorm

Tags: typescript, gulp, webstorm

I'm using gulp-typescript to compile my TypeScript and I use WebStorm. Currently, compilation errors appear in my output window and I'd like to be able to double-click them to go to the line TypeScript has identified. In VSCode, you can add those errors to the IDE, but I don't see how with WebStorm.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: just as a note, VisualCode does not rely on gulp to show the errors, it compiles itself (most likely using tsc directly). Maybe look for a TypeScript plugin for WebStorm?

Comment: this page seems to show how to set WebStorm for typescript. :) https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/typescript-support.html

Comment: I just installed WebStorm 11 and it works fine with my projects, what's your setup?

Comment: Guys, please note I want to use Gulp, not the TypeScript integration. The normal integration works fine, but I want it as a gulp task. Also VSCode allows you to pipe gulp errors to its error output so it hooks up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't work currently, please vote for [WEB-19636](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19636)